wnctrl is not minimizing my Terminal
This works..
xdotool search  "Mozilla Firefox" windowminimize

but this does not minimize my Terminal.
xdotool search  "Terminal" windowminimize
Defaulting to search window name, class, and classname

wmctrl -l
0x01400003 -1 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M Top Panel
0x01400017 -1 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M Bottom Panel
0x01400025 -1 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M Top Panel
0x01600006 -1 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M Desktop
0x02800007  0 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M Downloads - Thunar
0x0360003e  0 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M How to minimize an application window from command line - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange — Mozilla Firefox
0x03800006  0 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M Terminal
0x03c00007  0 andy-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M *untitled - Geany

Why isn't my Terminal being minimized?

Yeah, it doesn't work for me either. I wonder if it has anything to do with what is mentioned here in this related answer:

Xdotool can be used to send input to a window that's not in the front. However, not all windows will accept such input. For example, xterm will not unless you check the "Allow Send Events" options. Chromium doesn't either. However, Firefox at least as of 2019, does work.

In any case, using xdotool to press the following keyboard shortcut works on regular Ubuntu (tested on Ubuntu Unity):
xdotool search --class terminal key --window %@ "ctrl+super+Down"

Some research shows that XFCE uses alt+f9 to minimize and alt+f10 to maximize so if the previous command doesn't work, then try this instead:
xdotool search --class terminal key --window %@ "alt+F9"

I realize this is kind of a hacky workaround but it seems to work, at least.
Lastly, if you ever have trouble with or need to know a key name, this list of xdotool key codes can be used to fall back on.

Thanks mchid. It worked perfectly. :-)
